# UITableView is preloading every cell

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UITableView inside of a scrollview. I load the datasource from internet content in the background, then call "reloadData". But, it loads EVERY cell. As far as I know, it is supposed to load the cells as they appear onscreen. What is going on?

Comment: `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation. Go.

Comment: I think it's a quite good question without code example. Also `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not used to hint which rows are visible and by the question is sounds a user1007892 has a working `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it happens because a `UIScrollView` itself does not take care of figuring out which subviews to be shown or not, thats up to a subclass or a delegate.

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

> The object that manages the drawing of content displayed in a scroll view should tile the content’s subviews so that no view exceeds the size of the screen. As users scroll in the scroll view, this object should add and remove subviews as necessary.

And if you add a table view inside a scroll view I think the table view will load as many cells as needed to draw its bounds without knowing which parts of it that really is on the screen.